# OpenFileDialog filter files with NO extension

Tags: file, openfiledialog

I'm using an OpenFileDialog and I would like to only show files with NO extension,

I've tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "DICOMDIR Files|" + null;
    ofd.FileName = string.Empty;
    ofd.Multiselect = false;
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own custom dialog.   No other way to do it.